# Поиск по Яндекс карте IOS

Tags: ios, swift, search, yandexmapkit, uikit

Не могу понять, как реализовать поиск по Яндекс карте. Нужно сделать так, как в Яндекс такси, только в старой версий, чтобы при нажатии на совпадение адреса, карта автоматически ставила пин и зуммила карту в нужном месте. Если у кого-то есть проект с подробным описанием поиска, то пожалуйста оставьте ссылку

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Почитайте статью Яндекса о мобильном геопоиске на хабре. Это может прояснить суть. https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/